# Get Rank User with PHP/MySQL Without Inserting Current User's Score into the table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a web-based game I'm creating in PHP with a MySQLi database. I'm looking to get the 'rank' of a user but it's a little different than other answers I've seen on here.

The user finishes the game and their score, time and rank will show on the final page. Then, they can choose to signup and save their score AFTER the game. So I need to be able to get the rank of the user compared to where it would fit into the already populated table without actually inserting it into the table.

My 'score' table is set up with rows

- ID (primary index/auto incremental)
- Username
- Score
- Time

Essentially, if a user has an identical score to another user, it then checks the time variable and ranks it with that secondary option.

Comment: can u attach your code here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could incorporate the new score into a query something like

```
SELECT id, username, score, time FROM scores
UNION ALL
SELECT 0 as id, 'YOURSCORE' as username, 99999 as score, 45 as time
ORDER BY score desc, time desc
```